# Is there a consumable that removes curses?

Tags: for-the-king

There are healing items and status removal items, but is there anything that will remove curses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumable herb, Hag's Bane, will remove all curses from a character or creature. They can be acquired either from a mob, occasionally from the shop in town, or from treasure chests. Check out this link [here](https://fortheking.gamepedia.com/Cursed) for more information.